# Finding pixels containing 0

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm trying to calculate the pixels within a range. I calculated the range, but I can't count the pixels containing 0.

My code:

```
first_value_of_i = zeros(M,1);
first_value_of_j = zeros(N,1);

second_value_of_i = zeros(M,1);
second_value_of_j =zeros(N,1);
    
for i = 2:M-1       
    for j = 2:N-1
                    
        Pix = [image(i,j) image(i-1,j) image(i-1,j+1) image(i,j+1) image(i+1,j+1) image(i+1,j) image(i+1,j-1) image(i,j-1) image(i-1,j-1) image(i-1,j)];
         
        if((Pix(1)==0) && ( (Pix(2)*Pix(3)*Pix(4)*Pix(5)*Pix(6)==0) || (Pix(2)*Pix(6)*Pix(7)*Pix(8)*Pix(9)==0)))
            
            if (((Pix(2)+Pix(6)+Pix(7)+Pix(8)+Pix(9))>=5) || ((Pix(2)+Pix(3)+Pix(4)+Pix(5)+Pix(6))>=5))             
                first_value_of_i(i,1) = i;
                first_value_of_j(j,1) = j;
            end
            
            if (((Pix(2)+Pix(3)+Pix(4)+Pix(8)+Pix(9))>=5) || ((Pix(4)+Pix(5)+Pix(6)+Pix(7)+Pix(8))>=5))             
                second_value_of_i(i,1) = i;
                second_value_of_j(j,1) = j;
            end               
            
        end % if
        
    end %for
        
end %for
    
rest_stroke = zeros(M,2);

for p = first_value_of_i : second_value_of_i
    
    count_rest=0;
    
    for q = first_value_of_j:second_value_of_j                      
        if((image(p,q)==0))
            count_rest=count_rest+1;
        end        
    end
                
    rest_stroke(i,1)=i;
    rest_stroke(i,2)=count_rest; 
end
```

But the output shows:

> Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.
>
> Error in trying (line 173)
> if((image(p,q)==0))

According to my calculation it should be ok, but evidently, it is not. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: I would debug your code by stepping through it and watch the values of `p` and `q`. Clearly one of them is either zero or negative at some point.

Comment: `first_value_of_i` and other similarly named indices are initialzed using `zeros()`... that's probably a good place to start.

Comment: Thank u so much for the help.

Answer (score 2):

```
for i=2:M-1

    for j = 2:N-1
```

`i` begins at 2. `first_value_of_i(1,1)` is initialized as 0 and not changed.

Comment: instead of using `zeros()`, maybe use `ones()`?

Comment: @ElijahRockers no idea what op wants to do, why is the first entry left untouched